# What should be the memory usage alert criteria for Cockroachdb running in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cockroachdb

I am using cockroach DB cluster on GKE and I'm monitoring with Prometheus and have imported this [Grafana Dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11466/)

However, there are 4 types of RAM usage within the graph(RSS, goallocated,gototal,cgo allocated), therefore I'm not able to decide on which parameter there is possibility of high RAM usage and how can I set an alert?

Can you please guide If anyone of you have used this before?

Answer (score 0):

You want to monitor RSS ([Resident set size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size)) and compare it against the maximum amount of virtual memory you want CockroachDB to use.

The others metrics as documented [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cluster-setup-troubleshooting.html#suspected-memory-leak) are:

- **RSS**: Total memory in use by CockroachDB.
- **Go Allocated**: Memory allocated by the Go layer.
- **Go Total**: Total memory managed by the Go layer.
- **CGo Allocated**: Memory allocated by the C layer.
- **CGo Total**: Total memory managed by the C layer.